# How do I install an older version of Rails with rbenv? Why is the rails command missing after installed version 5.2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I installed rbenv, and then ruby version 2.6.1.

I cloned my rails app from github, installed the bundler gem, ran `bundle` and watched it install all of the gems from my Gemfile.

Now comes time to run the app with the rails command. I go to install rails with `gem install rails -v 5.2.3`, the version my app uses in its Gemfile.

When I run `which rails` there is no output, and running `rails` at the prompt says command not found.

This is the output from running `gem install rails -v 5.2.3`. I thought there would be more things installed...

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-13-159:~/lms-rails$ gem install rails -v 5.2.3
Successfully installed rails-5.2.3
Parsing documentation for rails-5.2.3
Installing ri documentation for rails-5.2.3
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Why is the rails command missing? Did I forget to add something to my path?
`PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims`

Comment: Is Rails not in your Gemfile? `bundle exec rails` doesn't just work? I sometimes also need to hash/rehash to get newly-installed executables to work, but I've never been sure why.

Comment: You can also run `bin/rails` to run the binstub.

Comment: You shouldn't install Rails with `gem install rails`, it should be installed automatically with `bundle install` as long as Rails is in your Gemfile. If you still can't run rails, try [`bundle install --binstubs`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-binstubs.1.html), then retry running rails.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the `bundle install --binstubs` suggestion, that seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rbenv versions`  command, this  will lists all Ruby versions known to rbenv, and shows an asterisk next to the currently active version.

Then swicth to version desired with [rbenv global](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-global) or [rbenv local](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-versions) and restart the terminal, then install the desired gems, anything should be fine.